# Installing Alma linux on Laptop with Intel Optane SSD shows up error md126

Tags: linux, laptop, ssd

I have purchased a laptop with Windows, I wanted to install Ala linux. I have downloaded the latest version of the distribution and have made a bootable USB.

Now when I start the installation process I see an error about missing file or something - md126.

I found information suggestion that it might be due to the mode of the SSD, which should be AHCI. I have chcked in the BOOT menu , there were only two options, no RAID option available:

- AHCI
- Intel Optane Premium Technology

I have tried to turn it to AHCI and restart the booting, still same error, however now the windows won't load. I have siwtched it back to Intel Optane tech, now it works.

Can you suggest me what should I do to install the linux, and remove the windows, is it because of the BIOS setting or maybe the flash is not set up correctly? What can I check?

Comment: This [link](https://codenotary.com/blog/ubuntu-how-to-use-intel-optane-memory-for-ssd-caching) might be useful.

Comment: Removing Windows might not be the best idea but if you want to install Alma Linux then the Optane status doesn't matter. Disable it as mentioned in the link in the 1st comment and understand what you can and can't do with a dual-boot in that PC. That said the error you're getting is probably due to a corrupt ISO. If not that then you probably should use one of this - https://repo.almalinux.org/almalinux/9/live/x86_64/ - in an USB. The DVD images may work also with Ventoy.